# I want to create a bucket in ibm cloud with Public Access. Anyone should be able to access it?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I have good experience with AWS, but recently I needed to work with IBM cloud, I am totally new to it. What I want is to create a bucket in a cloud storage object. The bucket should have public access. I want to get a URL by which I can download content from the bucket directly inside another computer located in another country. I already created a bucket inside the cloud storage object but in the console, under the public access column, it is Showing no to public access. Also, I searched for an endpoint for the bucket which I am not able to find anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can find the endpoints to access a COS bucket under the **Endpoints** section in the left nav:

[image: Endpoints in left nav]

2. To configure Public Access, select your bucket, then under **Access Policies**, create a policy to grant **Public Access**.

[image]